# Django filtering a queryset for items less than half an hour old

Tags: django

```
class Action(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='actions')
    date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True, blank=True)
```

Using this as an example, say I wanted to filter all actions by a particular user that are less than half an hour old?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
thirty_minutes_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=30)

Action.objects.filter(date__gte=thirty_minutes_ago)
```